# How can I complete "Waking Nightmare"?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've found the potion Vaermina's Torpor but the next script has never been triggered, i.e. I can't tell him that I got that potion. I don't have that option:

> Your next stop will be the Laboratory, where Vaermina's Torpor should be stored.  There are some more Invader Orcs and Vaermina Devotees that will need to be dealt with  as you go along. When Vaermina's Torpor is located, Erandur instructs you to drink it  and upon doing so, you become Casimir, a Vaermina Devotee during the Orc raid on the  temple. You are instructed to release the Miasma to protect the Skull.

I've tried to reset the character to no avail:

> It is possible that reseting his location to the player will resolve this issue (open the console and type "prid 0024280" and then "moveto player").

When I try to drink the potion I receive the message:

> Quest item cannot be eat.

Similar happens when I try to remove it:

> Quest item cannot be remove from inventary.

How can I solve the quest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct console code is `setstage DA16 120`. This allows you to talk to him and drink it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to go back to Erandur and tell him you found the potion. He'll ask you if you are ready to drink it (the typical 'Are you sure?' before being teleported to a quest area). Before you do that, you can't drink the potion.

Comment: Yeah, once you tell him you have it he will walk back to where the barrier is located and THEN you should be able to drink it

Comment: @Andy_Vulhop: I can't tell him. I don't have that option?

Comment: @SomeMiscGuy: I can't tell him. I don't have that option?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to try to drop the potion and pick it back up. If that doesn't work, try to reload a save. If you're on pc, you can just use console codes to advance to the next stage of the quest.

Comment: I can't drop the potion it's a quest item. What is the console code to advance to the next stage?

Answer (score 0):

If you're standing in the right location while trying to talk to him (the top level of the laboratory), and things are seeming all buggy and he won't talk to ya, try the console command setstage DA16 110 ([source](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Waking_Nightmare)). Hopefully that'll move you right along.